# How can I work on a game that I don't like?

Tags: project-management

I started making a game with a friend, and I want to see it through. But the deeper we get into the project, the more I dislike the game.

How can I stay motivated and keep getting things done, if I don't really feel invested in the end product?

Comment: I suggest you try: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/ and these related questions: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/85/

Answer (score 1):

Find something in the project that you are really invested in. Even if the ultimate game isn't that thing, hopefully there's some part of the project that you can connect with.

For example, for me it's often about the new technology that I'm learning. Even if I'm meh about the end product, usually I get pretty jazzed about all the new techniques that I'm learning while I work.